# Norm on cotangent space and Hölder's inequality on Riemannian manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, tensors

Let $(\mathcal{M}, g)$ be a Riemannian $n$-manifold. We know that

$$
  \Vert v \Vert_g := \langle v, v \rangle_g^\frac{1}{2}
$$

defines a norm on the tangent space $T_p \mathcal{M}$. Can we derive the norm $\Vert \cdot \Vert_*$ of $T_p^* \mathcal{M}$ from $\Vert \cdot \Vert_g$? Would simply defining $\Vert \omega \Vert_* := \Vert \omega^\sharp \Vert_g$ works?

In particular, I'm interested in knowing whether Hölder's inequality holds on $T_p \mathcal{M}$, i.e.

$$
  \sum_{k=1}^n \vert v_k w_k \vert \leq \Vert v \Vert_g \Vert w \Vert_* \, ,
$$

for any $v, w \in T_p \mathcal{M}$. (Though when $\Vert \cdot \Vert_*$ is defined to be $T_p^* \mathcal{M} \to \mathbb{R}$, that doesn't make sense.)

Is there any other definition of dual norm on tangent space of Riemannian manifold, such that Hölder's inequality holds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what the $\sharp$ symbol means, but any scalar product $g(\cdot, \cdot) $on a finite dimensional vector space $X$ induces a natural isomorphism from $X$ to $X^*$ by mapping $v$ to $\omega_v$ by letting $\omega_v(w):= g(v, w)$.

You can request this to be an isometry, which induces a norm and a scalar product on $X^*$ in a natural way (so $||\omega_v||= ||v||$)

It's not difficult to see that then $g^*(\omega_v,\omega_w) = g(v,w)$.

These definitions easily carry over naturally and continuously to the tangent bundle construction.

(If that matches the inverse of your $\sharp$ map then your pertaining question is answered by yes :-)

I'm not sure what kind of Hölder inequality you want, but clearly $$||\omega_v(w)||= ||g(v,w)||\le ||v||\,||w|| = ||\omega_v||\,||w||$$

by the Cauchy Schwartz inequality for $g$ and using the fact that the map in question is an isometry.

Comment: [FYI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musical_isomorphism).

Comment: Thanks! I have a follow-up (or a rephrased) question: Is it always possible to define p-norms in a tangent space? Or is the only norm exists in a tangent space is the norm induced by $g$?

Comment: @wiseodd Please consider to create new questions for follow-ups. Discussing answers or extensions to answers is not well received here.